# What is the WordPress code to toggle 'Leave a Reply'

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

I know I can just delete that (every post seems to be about deleting it)

I also know I can 'hard code' comments onto a page with

```
<?php $withcomments = "1"; comments_template(); ?>
```

My question (and please point me to another answer if I have missed it - I have looked!) is how do I enable the toggle 'discussion' under screen options (i.e. if I toggle it to off what is the conditional statement I need in order to allow this toggle to work on each page.)

i.e.

```
if(comments_template_enabled()){comments_template();}
```

Or do I have to change the logic somewhere else?

After searching the codex to no avail I am asking a noob question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen options determine what you see on the admin page. You need to check Discussion then scroll down to find the discussion box. From there you can choose to enable or disable comments.

Comment: Hi Nathan - I am aware of this but it still shows discussions on the site - when i check that tick box (or uncheck it) where does that point (which file) as I am guessing something isn't correct in that file.

Comment: The file is comments.php